# Is there any standard to assigning name to your token symbol?

Tags: ico, symbol-name, token-standard

If some one creating new tokens. So the name of token symbol can be any string. If someone wants, he can give a string of length 20 or anything he want.
My question is,  How can we decide the **symbol** name of a token?

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge there is limitation in token symbole that you can only use uppercase characters, no numbers are allowed and only 7 characters are allowed as symbol.

Comment: Yes we can define the length in our create action. But generally what people follow? As our EOS token we have only 3 characters something like that

Comment: As i know you cannot define length in create action it is set by default and that limit is 7(as per my experiance) and people follows as per their requirement for symbol name for an example i am an owner of company called "TokenMaker" and if i want to make a token on eosio so i can choose name as "TKNMKR" which is having length of 6 and it is allowed.